# Cassandra 1.2 CQL query set

Tags: select, cassandra, set, where-clause

I have a table in Cassandra containing name, item.

Using the following data types: name is text, item is `set<text>`.

f.e. I have these entries:

```
name | item
a    | {item1, item3}
b    | {item2, item3}
c    | {item1, item2}
```

Now my question: Is there any way to get all names having item1?

I tried this, but didn't work:

```
SELECT name 
FROM table 
WHERE item = 'item1';
```

I get an error that 'item1' is a string, but item is a `set<text>`.

I guess there is a way to do this, but I can't think of how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlikely this is not yet supported in Cassandra. May be in some upcoming version  we will be able to index even collection items.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Guess I have to think about a different solution.